# Doctrine targetEntity abstract class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, many-to-one

I get unnecessary queries then entity has `ManyToOne` relationship with abstract class.
My classes structure:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tb_payment_info")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *          "0" = "PaymentInfoPaypal",
 *          "1" = "PaymentInfoSkrill",
 * })
 */
abstract class AbstractPaymentInfo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment_info_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tb_payment_info_paypal")
 */
class PaymentInfoPaypal extends AbstractPaymentInfo
{
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tb_payment_info_skrill")
 */
class PaymentInfoSkrill extends AbstractPaymentInfo
{
}
```

My `Payout` class contains `payment_info_id` column from `tb_payment_info` table.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tb_payout")
 */
class Payout
{
    /**
     * @var AbstractPaymentInfo
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AbstractPaymentInfo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="payment_info_id", referencedColumnName="payment_info_id")
     */
    private $paymentInfo;
}
```

When I try to get any `Payout` entity, its `paymentInfo` initialize automatically. So:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('TuoPayBundle:Payout')->find(255);
```

got 2 queries: first for `Payout` and second for its `paymentInfo`

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('TuoPayBundle:Payout')->findBy(['id'=>[255,256]]);
```

got 3 queries: first for `Payout` and second, third separate queries to init `paymentInfo`

How to achieve lazy load?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare an abstract class in Doctrine 2 with `@ORM\Entity` notation. If you want to use abstract classes in your object model I suggest you check [the documentation on **Mapped Superclasses**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) on how to do that correctly.

Most importantly you should declare the class with a special `@ORM\MappedSuperClass` annotation.

Keep in mind that Mapped superclasses come with restrictions. I quote:

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all. Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance features have to be used.

Comment: I try to use MappedSuperClass before this post. But I get Exception: Its not supported to define inheritance information on a mapped superclass

Comment: What exception. Maybe post a separate question about that...? I am sure that what you do here is not correct and will lead to issues!

Comment: You are mixing up class inheritance and abstract mapping. You should maybe consider only using abstract mapping for common properties and skip the inheritance...

Comment: In google I found that it occures because of ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED"). I don't try, but google say me that with ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE") it work's fine. But I need "JOINED". So we must found another approach.

Comment: On **[Google](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/90/69/55/906955ddebb869ec8fb4797509a37ca3.jpg)** you can find a lot of things. You should refer to the official documentation.